# Может ли произойти OutOfMemoryException для small heap

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Может ли произойти OutOfMemoryException для small heap или такой exception возможен только для large heap?
Если это возможно, то что вызывает  OutOfMemoryException для small heap? Есть ли инструмент, демонстрирующий для какой кучи произошел  OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: Не small heap (маленькая куча), а small object heap (куча маленьких объектов). Да, OOM может произойти. Думаю, любой профайлер может показать распределение потребления памяти по размеру объектов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а я все гадаю, что за small heap :)

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, чуточку распишу.

Нет таких понятий - small heap (маленькая куча), large heap (большая куча). Но есть small object heap (куча маленьких объектов), large object heap (куча больших объектов).

Исключение `OutOfMemory` происходит не в какой-то куче, а в системе в целом. Например, имеется 1000 единиц (кб/Мб/Гб - не суть) свободной памяти (непрерывным куском). Если сперва выделить 999 единиц памяти под большой объект, а потом 2 единицы под маленький, то OOM вылетит при создании маленького. Наоборот, если сперва выделить 2 едииницы памяти под маленький объект, а потом 999 единиц под большой, то OOM вылетит при создании большого.

Comment: Александр, спасибо!